# Application name on Java GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

There is any way to get by code the application name on Java GAE?

I need to configure some objects according with my application instance (production or development), and I want to build a automatic way.

Comment: Do you use a dependency injection framework like Guice or Spring?

Comment: I don't use none of this dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [App Identity](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/overview.html)

Calling:

```
String serviceAccountName = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService().getServiceAccountName();
```

The `serviceAccountName` will be set as `<app name>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

Answer (score 2):

```
String ID = SystemProperty.applicationId.get();
```

You can find more details at the following URL

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_environment

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the app id:

```
ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAppId()
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/?csw=1#Java_Identifying_itself